# Regarding Dns VPN related

Tags: vpn, dns

We are providing remote IT support to client X from our office. To connect to client X's network we were using Cisco vpn on individual computers. But today all of the sudden our office management asked us to switch the lan cable to different port after doing so without connecting to VPN we were able to access client X's private network from our office network. How this is possible. What technology or configuration is involved in this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well what is different for the network of the first Ethernet connection vs the other? That is pretty crucial information for us to assist you

Answer (score 2):

> But today all of the sudden our office management asked us to switch the lan cable to different port after doing so without connecting to VPN we were able to access client X's private network from our office network.

VPN can exist on the router level.

A common situation is for branch offices to connect back to a main office through a business Internet connection, with a *site-to-site* VPN running on top of it.  Since the router is handling the VPN, you don't have to run any software on the client computers.

Of course, when you leave the office and want to work from home, you'll need to still use the VPN software to connect - since your home router isn't running the same software.

So it sounds like your office got a site-to-site VPN setup completed and you no longer need to use VPN software in the office.